# Get only word part of an id/name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element with lots of descendent's elements, all with ids in the form "word1", for a simple example: `id="moviment1"` or `id="type1"`.
I need to get only the written part of these ids (`moviment` or `type`), in order to concatenate their names with a increment of 1 (`id="moviment2"` or `id="type2"`).

```
$clone.find('*').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).prop('id');
                var num = parseInt( $(this).prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
                $(this).prop('id', id+num);
            });
```

The way it is, I always get ids like `id="moviment12"`. I already tried:

```
var id = $(this).prop('id').replace(/\d+/g, '');
```

or

```
var id = $(this).prop('id').match(/\w+/);
```

But I always get errors like `"cannot read property 'replace'/'match' of undefined"`. So, what am I doing wrong? Any other ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you just want to remove the numbers, then `id = this.id.replace(/\d/g,'')`. BTW, `$(this).prop("id")` is a seriously inefficient way to write `this.id`.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Why don't you use a template instead of the cloning?

Comment: Some links that I found might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/FKuWJ/1/ and https://coderwall.com/p/k-qavq/jquery-copy-clone-element-and-increment-index-based-on-attribute

Comment: Or you can use knockout js. It is pretty easy and saves your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var onlyAlphabets = id.split(/(\d)/)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use a template. Traversing and modifying parsed elements makes your code slow and hard to maintain.

If you want to increment the number part of the IDs by 1 you can use the `replace` method callback function:

```
$clone.find('[id]').prop('id', function(_, id) {
    // Assuming `id` is `test_25_segment`
    return id.replace(/(\d+)/, function(num) {
    //                                   |
    //                                   --- is 25 
         return +num + 1;
    //          |
    //          --- parses the matching string into integer 
    });
});
```

[Here is a demo using the above snippet.](http://jsfiddle.net/euvrdyc5/)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, you could just add those values as `data-attr`:

```
<div id="type1" data-id="1" data-text="type"></div>
```

So you can easily get them separated just using `.data('id')` and `.data('text')`.

Answer (score 1):

You may select the elements by this way:

```
var all = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id*=type]'), function(el) {
    return (/\btype\d+\b/).test(el.id);
});
```

and then you can change the ids using methods like `replace()`